# Same ExceptionMapper for different exceptions

Tags: java, rest, jersey

My application provides a RESTful interface to perform some actions. I'm using `ExceptionMapper` to catch exceptions like `NoResultException` or `EntityNotFoundException` and then return an status code of 404, or exceptions like `NumberFormatException` or `ConstraintViolationException` and return an status code of 400... etc.

My problem is that the `ExceptionMapper` only allows me to choose one kind of Exception each time; so I can't use the same class for all the error 400 and other form all the error 404.

Is there any way to create an `ExceptionMapper` that maps two different kind of exceptions?

My other option is change my functions to return a Response instead of an String (tagged as `@Produces("application/json"));` and then set the status code each time; but I think it's worst...

Answer (score 6):

You could write a single ExceptionMapper against an exception superclass (i.e. `java.lang.Exception`) and then provide different behaviors based on the specific exception class, for example:

```
public class MyExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<Exception> {
    @Override
    public Response toResponse(Exception exception) {
        if (exception instanceof EntityNotFoundException) {
            ...
        }
        else (exception instanceof NumberFormatException) {
            ...
        }
        else {
            // The catch-all handler...
        }
    }
}
```

But in my opinion this isn't as clean as writing separate mappers for each type of exception. For one thing, this mapper will catch all Exceptions, and for another this class could grow to unwieldy dimensions over time. Perhaps it's a matter of code style.

Comment: I thought in this too; but as you say isn't clean. In fact; you can write several ExceptionMappers for different classes and a ExceptionMapper of a superclass of them (like Exception); and the exceptions with a specific ExceptionMapper will use it; and all the others will use the ExceptionMapper of its superclass.

Comment: I'd still prefer a bunch of instanceof checks vs. fragmenting this logic across several needlessly tiny classes and losing sight of the big picture, i.e. what response codes are returned for what sorts of exceptions